# Sunspot Rails 503 error on Reindexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using the sunspot_rails gem and the sunspot_solr gem in my Rails 4 app for searching and indexing, I am following the steps on [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot?view=asciicast), and it seemed to be working for a bit, but when I went to reindex my data after changing what I am searching on I kept getting the following error:

```
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - ignoring...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
```

Which repeats until I kill the rake task. I searched and googled trying to find out why this is happening, but I couldn't find anything useful. Has anyone encountered this error / knows how to fix it?

If it's relevant here are the other two bits of code I have for sunspot search so far:

```
#search_controller

    @search = Content.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
        paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 300
    end

    p @search.results.count

    render :json => @search.results


#search_model  

     Class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
        searchable do
            text :company_name, :boost => 3
            text :file_num, :ccn, :country, :content
        end
     end
```

Here are the relevant gems too

```
#Gemfile

    gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'progress_bar'
```

Edit:

After running `ps aux | grep solr` I get the following:

```
47900            2780   0.0  0.8  8286720 141284   ??  Ss   10:40AM   0:12.99 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.port=8982 -Dsolr.data.dir=/Users/47900/Desktop/UL/OCD-V-Search-Engine/solr/data/development -Dsolr.solr.home=/Users/47900/Desktop/UL/OCD-V-Search-Engine/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/folders/d_/vm32mms91ql8p9mpzxfsqr7snbfhc_/T/logging.properties20150914-2780-1ncrn5s -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar start.jar
47900           84679   0.0  0.0  2451204    720 s000  S+   12:47PM   0:00.00 grep solr
```

Comment: Are you sure that solr is still running when you get 503?

Comment: How would I check that it's still running? I'm pretty sure it is, but just to be sure

Comment: type ps aux | grep solr into the command prompt and tell me what it returns

Comment: Edited it into the original question. Any insight?

Comment: check if the data directory has the space available? /Users/47900/Desktop/UL/OCD-V-Search-Engine/solr/data/development